# Why is this unordered_map not finding existing keys? (C++14)

Tags: c++, c++14

I'm trying to use an `unordered_map` for a custom type. However, the map is storing duplicate entries, which have the same hash value and *should* evaluate as equal when using ==.

I've reduced my code to the following proof of concept, where I can see that the hash function runs correctly, but the equals operator is never called.

```
#include <unordered_map>

// Define a class with a single integer member.
class Example
{
  public: int x;
  public: Example(int x)
  {
    this->x = x;
  }

  // Overload == and compare the single member.
  public: bool operator==(const Example &other) const
  {
    std::cout << "Comparing two objects\n";
    return this->x == other.x;
  }
};

// Define a hash function class
class ExampleHash
{
  public: size_t operator()(const Example* key) const
  {
    // simply return the member variable as the hash value.
    std::cout << "Returning hash value " << key->x << "\n";
    return key->x;
  }
};

int main()
{
  // Create an empty map.
  std::unordered_map<Example*, int, ExampleHash> m;

  std::cout << "Inserting a new key\n";      

  // Insert an object with the value 1.
  m[new Example(1)] = 1;

  std::cout << "Existing hashes:\n";
  ExampleHash fn;
  for (auto const &item : m) {
    size_t h = fn(item.first);
    std::cout << "  " << h << ", ";
  }
  std::cout << "\n";

  std::cout << "Finding the key\n";

  // Check if the object is in the map.
  std::cout << ((m.find(new Example(1)) != m.end()) ? "Found" : "Not found") << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Inserting a new key
Returning hash value 1
Existing hashes:
Returning hash value 1
  1, 
Finding the key
Returning hash value 1
Not found
```

(Note the absence of the "Comparing two objects" line when calling `unordered_map::find`, despite the hash value clearly being in the map already.)

Comment: Your key is a pointer.  So each time you do 'new Example(1)', that's a different object/key.

Comment: Your `operator==(const Example &other)` is for an `Example&`, not an `Example*`.  Why are you storing pointers as your key type?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using a **pointer** as a key in a map.  A **pointer** as a key acts like a token, and you have to use that same token (or, the token's pointer value, to be precise) to retrieve something from the map.

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks for the heads-up (I'm new to C++'s pointer concept). When I tried to declare the map with `Example` instead of `Example*`, I was getting errors from `m[new Example(1)];` since `new` appears to return a pointer...

Comment: Pro tip, don't use new in C++.  For the most part, you don't need pointers, and if you do, use a smart one like `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` and their respective  `make_` functions.

Comment: Thanks very much! I hadn't realized this special significance of `new` and thought it was the only way to create an instance (as opposed to just calling `Example(1)`, which appears to work correctly after removing all the `*`). I think this solves the question!

Comment: `new` for all practical purposes is considered a *legacy* operator. The containers library has all but eliminated the need for its use. You still do need to know how to use it, because there are two-decades worth of old C++ that use it heavily, but there are much better options for new code now (pun intended).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointers are not the objects they point to.

You are using pointers as keys.  The objects equal operator will be ignored.